# How to use a Model with octet-stream data in requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Give a HTTP Filesystem API which accepts

```
GET /storage/filename
PUT /storage/filename
Request body: the file contents
```

and these headers

```
Content-Length: ...
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

How can one build a backbone.js File Model which works with it? (e.g. get file contents in a variable, put back updated contents)

If backbone.js doesn't support this, how would jQuery ajax requests look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't found support in jQuery/backbone, here's how it can be done:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "url", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
xhr.responseType = "text";

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var contents = this.response;
    console.log("RECEIVED " + contents);
   }
};

xhr.send();
```

More details at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/